# Clear an App Service instance and upload new content from a zip file

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service

On App Service, what's the best way of deploying new content from a zip file, such that it replaces any existing content?

Please note:

- I am running on linux
- I cannot use msdeploy
- I cannot use git
- I cannot use VSTS
- It needs to be simple
- It cant be prone to timing out
- It has to be supported by all subscription levels of App Service
- Commands should only return after their respective operation(s) have completed
- I have access to ARM templates
- Provided it isn't as difficult, I'm sure I could upload files to storage blobs

For more information, see this discussion here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2367

Comment: Thanks for asking this question.  Almost exactly the same one I've been wondering about for the last 3 days!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a solution that consists in calling the ARM msdeploy provider to deploy a cloud hosted zip package. This requires no msdeploy on your client, so the fact that msdeploy technology is involved is mostly an implementation detail you can ignore.

There are a couple gotchas that I will call out at the end.

The steps are:

- First, get your zip hosted in the cloud. e.g. I have a test one here you can play around with: https://davidebbostorage.blob.core.windows.net/arm/FunctionMsDeploy.zip (note that this zip uses special msdeploy packaging, but you can also use a plain old zip with just your files).
- Then run the following command using cli 2.0, replacing your resource group, app name and zip url:

  ```
  az resource update --resource-group MyRG --namespace Microsoft.Web --parent sites/MySite --resource-type Extensions --name MSDeploy --set properties.packageUri=https://davidebbostorage.blob.core.windows.net/arm/FunctionMsDeploy.zip --api-version 2015-08-01
  ```

This will result in the package getting deployed to your `wwwroot`, and any existing content that's not in the zip getting deleted. It's efficient as it won't touch any files that already exist and are identical to what's in the zip. So it's far faster than trying to clean out everything and unzipping clean (but results are identical).

Now a couple gotchas:

- Due to what seems like a bug in CLI 2.0, I wasn't able to pass a URL that contains an equal sign, which rules out SAS URLs. I'll report that to them. For now, test the process with a public zip, like my test package above.
- The command line is more complex than it should be. I will also ask the CLI team about this.

Comment: Hi David, you are absolutely right, there is a bug in the --set parsing.  https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/2527

It is scheduled to be fixed in early April.

Comment: David, this is a great answer!  How does one easily build that zip file?  The format looks somewhat "special" and I wonder if it can be built by tooling on linux or do we need to "homebrew" the file ourselves.  If so, is there some doc somewhere that describes the required bits of the file format and how they change for different types of deployments?

Comment: Also, is there a way to avoid the az resource update command and use the ARM template directly to do this deployment since we're updating the ARM template anyway as part of our build process?

Comment: You should actually be able to use a completely normal zip. The one I shared is indeed special. Try just zipping up all the files you want to deploy, no sugar added.

Comment: Yes, you can use ARM template. See [here](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/b3b4680c67483394d71fd9a1e3404dc911f19877/ARMTemplates/FunctionsWebDeploy.json#L69-L80) for example.

Comment: I have some examples of a build flow which are publicly available on github and the builds themselves are public on travis CI: http://github.com/atrauzzi/anecdote-azure and http://travis-ci.org/atrauzzi/anecdote-azure - Feel free to strike up a discussion!

Comment: David, Thanks SOOO much.  This is going to be awesome.

Comment: Alright, I have actual proof of this working!  You can see the build log at this URL: https://travis-ci.org/atrauzzi/anecdote-azure/builds/214773609 - and you can see a nice clean example of how you can call it from bash here: https://github.com/atrauzzi/anecdote-azure/blob/master/bin/deploy-functions#L69-L76 - thank you so much @DavidEbbo!